# javascript http request lag

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm having what appears to be a timing issue when pulling large data files.  Sometimes the statement after "getFileData(selectedFile)" executes before the file is downloaded, and the statement fails.  I'm contemplating a "pause" function, but there has to be something better.

```
$("#dropDown").change(function (){
  var selectedFile = $("#dropDown").val();
  var text = getFileData(selectedFile);

  var valueLength = text.constructs[0].data_sections[0].values.length;
  var errorLength = text.constructs[0].data_sections[0].errors.length;
   . . . . 
   . . . .
   . . . .

});

var getFileData = function(fileName){

   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "http://xxx/xxx.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText.substr(0,xmlhttp.responseText(indexOf("<")));
        return response;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?q=" + fileName + ".txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

}

Comment: you should move all the code that relies on your var text into the callback function: xmlhttp.onreadystatechange - your xmlhttp request is non-blocking [which is good] - you tell it to be asynchronous by passing true here: xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?q=" + fileName + ".txt", true);

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest()` is asynchronous by nature. You should consider using a callback pattern (as suggested by pep's answer +1) or the use of promises.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, there's a better way: callback functions. If you are not familiar with callbacks, the code below might not make the most sense. I haven't tested it, but it should work or at least be close. Check this out for a reference on callbacks http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/.

```
$("#dropDown").change(function (){
  var selectedFile = $("#dropDown").val();
  var text = getFileData(selectedFile, function(response){
    //stuff that should not execute until XMLHttpRequest completes 
    var valueLength = response.constructs[0].data_sections[0].values.length;
    var errorLength = response.constructs[0].data_sections[0].errors.length;
     . . . . 
     . . . .
     . . . .
  });    
});

var getFileData = function(fileName, callback){

   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "http://xxx/xxx.php";

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText.substr(0,xmlhttp.responseText(indexOf("<")));
           callback(response);
       }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET", url + "?q=" + fileName + ".txt", true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In fact, the code you have would never work. Your `getFileData` function would always return before your HTTP request completes and therefore before your `return` statement gets hit. The callback pattern is extremely useful to learn and essentially allows you to provide code that gets executed after some delay, whether that delay be due to an HTTP request, an animation, you name it.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the lesson.  Here's the results.  http://www.wileyallc.com/test/JsonPHPTest2  Now I just have to figure out how to entertain the user while they wait for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery, you might as well use the jQuery [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. This function returns a [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object, and you can use the `deferred.done()` method to execute code when the AJAX request completes. `done()` accepts a single parameter which is a function that you want to run when the request is complete.

```
$("#dropDown").change(function (){
    var selectedFile = $("#dropDown").val();
    var deferred = getFileData(selectedFile);
    deferred.done(function (data) {
        var text = JSON.parse(data.substr(0, data.indexOf("<"));
        var valueLength = text.constructs[0].data_sections[0].values.length;
        var errorLength = text.constructs[0].data_sections[0].errors.length;
        . . . 
    });
});

var getFileData = function(fileName) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "http://xxx/xxx.php?q=" + fileName + ".txt"
    });
}
```

Note: this will do a GET request by default. If you ever want to do a POST, you can specify the type in the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://xxx/xxx.php?q=" + fileName + ".txt",
    type: "POST"
});
```